# log info doesn't show up on console but warn and error do

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to use the logging facility of python, but it does not work as expected.

Below is my code. It prints `warning` and `critical` messages properly, but it does not print `info` and `debug`. `getEffectiveLevel()` shows the correct level.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("base")

# set level to debug
logger1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

# check, if level is really DEBUG
print("effective level: " + str(logger1.getEffectiveLevel()))

logger1.debug   ("logger1: debug    msg")
logger1.info    ("logger1: info     msg")  
logger1.warning ("logger1: warning  msg")  
logger1.critical("logger1: critical msg")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

The missing information is a little bit hidden in the docs. You need to call

```
logging.basicConfig()
```

To initialize the `handlers`.

#### Complete Code

The full code would look like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("base")

# setup handlers
logging.basicConfig()

# set level to debug
logger1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

# check, if level is really DEBUG
print("efffective level: " + str(logger1.getEffectiveLevel()))

logger1.debug   ("logger1: debug    msg")
logger1.info    ("logger1: info     msg")  
logger1.warning ("logger1: warning  msg")  
logger1.critical("logger1: critical msg")
```

Also see how the printed messages changed.

#### Reference:

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html , search for `logging.log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)` and read the **Note**